# how to create a zoomable widget that when the pinch ends, the zoomed widget gets its initial position?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a Zoomable widget using [Matrix_Gesture_Detector](https://pub.dev/packages?q=matrix_gesture_detecto) package. I have created the widget with this code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:matrix_gesture_detector/matrix_gesture_detector.dart';
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math_64.dart';

class ZoomableWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const ZoomableWidget({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ZoomableWidgetState createState() => _ZoomableWidgetState();
}

class _ZoomableWidgetState extends State<ZoomableWidget> {
  Matrix4 defaultMatrix = Matrix4.diagonal3(
      Vector3(1.0.clamp(1.0, 5.0), 1.0.clamp(1.0, 5.0), 1.0.clamp(1.0, 5.0)));
  Matrix4 matrix;
  @override
  void initState() {
    matrix = defaultMatrix;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRect(
      child: MatrixGestureDetector(
        shouldTranslate: false,clipChild: true,focalPointAlignment: Alignment.center,
        shouldRotate: false,
        onMatrixUpdate: (Matrix4 m, Matrix4 tm, Matrix4 sm, Matrix4 rm) {
          setState(() {
            matrix = m;
          });
        },
        child: Transform(
          transform: matrix,
          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
          child: widget.child,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

now what I want is that when user releases the screen (the pinch ends) the widget go back to its initial position. any ides how can I achieve this?
also how can I prevent the zooming from zooming out that makes the container smaller from its original size?

Comment: you have to look into this
 https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view
https://pub.dev/packages/zoomable_image
https://pub.dev/packages/pinch_zoom_image

Comment: tried to run examples from `MatrixGestureDetector`? it has one example that checks the size of scaled object